# char and int in Java

Tags: java

I was surprised to see this code work.  I thought that char and int were two distinct data types in Java and that I would have had to cast the char to an int for this to give the ascii equivelent.  Why does this work?

```
String s = "hello";
int x = s.charAt(1);
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: `char` is a 16-bit unsigned value and `int` is a 32-bit signed value. You can assign a char to an int.

Answer (score 12):

A `char` can be automatically converted to an `int`. See [JLS 5.1.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2):

> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> ...
>
> - char to int, long, float, or double
>
> ...
>
> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format. **A widening conversion of a char to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the char value to fill the wider format.**

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 4):

`char` and `int` *are* two distinct types, but this works because an `int` has more precision than a `char`.  That is, every value of `char` can be represented as an `int` so no data is lost in the cast.