# When converting a char to a int in JAVA, why is no cast necessary?

Tags: java, casting

In Java I know you can convert char to ints like so:

```
int c = (int) msg.charAt(i);
```

But why does this also work with no errors:

```
int c = msg.charAt(i);
```

the function returns an int, so surely it needs to be "cast" to an int before using it.

DUPLICATE: Although the answer given by: [Why are we allowed to assign char to a int in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342988/why-are-we-allowed-to-assign-char-to-a-int-in-java) , the qusestion is slightly different. As I was not asking why we can assign a char to an int, rather I was asking why no cast is necessary. I'll suggest to keep this open for people on Google, even though its the same answer!

Comment: This will compile, but if you have to do calculation with this value, it will give you a wrong result. I'm just talking from my C# experience :)

Comment: The question is interesting but I had to mark it as duplicate. Just know that assigning `char` to `int` is allowed in C and was therefore allowed in Java.

Comment: @Minh I knew it compiles. I just wanted to know why it worked? thanks for the answer though.

Comment: A `char` has a value between 0 and 65535.  An `int` has a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.  As there is no possibility that "significance" will be lost doing the conversion, it happens automatically.  When a cast is used you're acknowledging that you know "overflow" may occur and you're accepting responsibility for that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.charAt` returns `char`. `char` to `int` is a widening primitive conversion (see JLS 5.1.2), this type of conversion does not lose information so it does not need an explicit cast