# How to get ASCII representation of a character?

Tags: java, ascii

I have very basic question.
How is possible for `int a = 'a'` to give `97` in output.

Below is my code:

```
class myClass {
    int last = 'a' ;

    myClass () {
        System.out.println(last );
    }

}
```

Comment: `'a'` is not a *String*, it is a *character*.

Comment: ASCII code for `a` is `97`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - char, int conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions)

Comment: Thanks, now is clear.

Comment: So, What now? Are you going to delete the question or aprove one of the answers or close the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this: [Why are we allowed to assign char to a int in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342988/why-are-we-allowed-to-assign-char-to-a-int-in-java)

Basically, you are assigning a `char` to your int. A `char` is technically an unsigned 16-bit character. That's why you can assign it to an int.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically cast the `char` to the `int` and store it as `int`:

```
  int a = (int)'a';
  System.out.println(a); //prints 97
```

Since Java can do the basic castings from your type specifications, you do not need to explicity write casting even.

```
  int a = 'a';
  System.out.println(a); // prints 97
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is the ASCII value of the character stored in *last*. The ASCII value of the character 'a' is 97, and hence the output on the console is 97.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take 'a' as a char
   `char char1 = 'a';`
then cast it to int
   `int num = (int) char1 ;`

Comment: This is not entirely correct, eg consider what happens if the character is not in ASCII: you'll still get an integer value.