# I want to convert uppercase letter to lowercase and vice versa

Tags: java

1. `char ch = 'A';`
2. `ch += 32;.  //This works fine`
3. `ch = ch + 32; //this doesn't work`

Why does line 2 work and line 3 doesn't, although they represent the same operation?

Comment: I believe that in the second case, the RHS `ch + 32` is being treated as a completely integer expression.

Comment: "doesnt work" - what does that mean? Please post the entire error code and the complete code to reproduce it ([mcve]).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use Character class static methods?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

```
Character.toUpperCase(ch)
```

Nevertheless to answer your question, java requires you to cast primitives when you would loose precision during the assignment, so when on the righand site you have 32bit int and on the lefthand side 16bit you need to explicitly cast it. So when a righthand side is an int, you need to cast. If you cast to char your code will work fine. Still just use Character class

```
    long l = 34; //this is fine     
    int i = 2L; //compile error, you loose precision in that assigment
```

Also check [Why are we allowed to assign char to a int in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342988/why-are-we-allowed-to-assign-char-to-a-int-in-java)