# Using char and int being in System.out.write() statement

Tags: java, system.out

I would like to pose 2 questions for the following program

```
class WriteDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    int b;

    b = 'x';

    System.out.write(b);
    System.out.write('\n');
   }
}
```

1. How can we use the character `'x'` for the variable b which is an integer?
2. The result of the program that appears on the screen is x. in case i remove the final line  `System.out.write('\n');` nothing appears on the screen.
   Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [char and int in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549692/char-and-int-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reverse order,

> The result of the program that appears on the screen is x. in case i remove the final line System.out.write('\n'); nothing appears on the screen.
>   Why is this happening?

Because the '\n' flushes the output buffers. You could also use,

```
System.out.write(b);
System.out.flush();
```

Your first question,

> How can we use the character 'x' for the variable b which is an integer?

[JLS-5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) provides for the widening -

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> ...
>
> `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`

Answer (score 3):

when you run

```
System.out.write(b);
```

you're actually calling this method at PrintStream class

```
/**
 * Writes the specified byte to this stream.  If the byte is a newline and
 * automatic flushing is enabled then the <code>flush</code> method will be
 * invoked.
 *
 * <p> Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that
 * will be translated according to the platform's default character
 * encoding, use the <code>print(char)</code> or <code>println(char)</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param  b  The byte to be written
 * @see #print(char)
 * @see #println(char)
 */
public void write(int b) {(...)
```

so if you flush your printer explicitly (or print a newline, as stated in the javadoc), you'll see the "x"

```
    System.out.write(b);
    System.out.flush();
```

about using 'x' as integer, I assume you're talking about what int number does x represent and how to print it.

Notice that if you do

```
System.out.println(b);
```

It will show you 120 because println will end up calling String.valueOf(b)