# Using a "char" when creating a new array: int[] a = new int['a']

Tags: java, arrays

While creating an array, we can pass `short`, `char`, `byte`, `int`. So, [why] is `int[] a = new int['a']` valid? It doesn't throw a compile time error.

What does an array declaration in this form mean?

Comment: `'a'` is a `char` literal.  In Java, `char` is a numeric type, so expressions of that type can be used where a number is required, including to specify the size of an array.

Comment: @Oleksandr I think this question is different enough from that.

Comment: @Sweeper And it's still effectively the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549716/2864740 D: (Although the answers given here are more precise and better formatted.)

Comment: When I Tried To Find The Length Of This Array. I Got 97. I Means int[] a = new int['a']; Is Actually Creating An Array With Length 97. 97 Is ASCII Value Of 'a'.

Comment: @ABD Please consider accepting the answer that has been the most helpful to you by clicking on that checkmark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [JLS Sec 15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1):

> The type of each dimension expression within a DimExpr must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to an integral type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.

And from [JLS Sec 5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1):

> If the operand is of compile-time type Byte, Short, Character, or Integer, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8). The result is then promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) or an identity conversion (§5.1.1).

and

> Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

So, any of `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `byte`, `short`, `char` or `int` are acceptable.

Hence `'a'`, a char literal, is allowed, and is promoted to the `int` value 97.

Answer (score 5):

Like most times with this kind of questions, the answer lies in the Java Language Specification:

> #### [§ 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - ***`char` to `int`***, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `long` to `float` or `double`
> - `float` to `double`

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

It may or may not be intuitive, but a `char` is actually an integral type, and the Java rules specify that primitive integral types may be converted to an integral type with a lower or higher-capacity. In this case, it's called a *widening primitive conversion*.

---

*[Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338964/507738) provides more references to the Java Language Specification, and explicitly states that an expression as in your question is valid.*

Answer (score 2):

According to the JLS §15.10.1 Array Creation Expressions,

> The type of each dimension expression within a DimExpr must be a type
> that is convertible (§5.1.8) to an integral type, or a compile-time
> error occurs.
>
> Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric
> promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time
> error occurs.

Here, unary numeric promotion occurs. Here is an excerpt from §5.6.1:

> ...if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or **char**, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

Therefore, `new int['a']` is valid.

If you are wondering how exactly is a char converted to an int, here is the relevant bits from §5.1.2:

> A widening conversion of a char to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the char value to fill the wider format.

Also note that characters are all encoded as integers.

Answer (score 1):

In java char is integer type (hello C++). This code do same `int[] a = new int[97];`

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a `char` type and it is implicitly casted to an integer with value `97` (ASCII representation, see details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set)). Therefore you are creating an array of length 97.

Comment: Actually, it creates an array of length **97**

Comment: Length Will Be 97.

Comment: @lealceldeiro yes, my bad, I looked at a wrong table, thanks! (: